# Fluctuating digital input on arduino uno r3 when connected to Photocoupler

Tags: arduino, opto-isolator

I am trying to use a Photocoupler [4N-25](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/775704_1.pdf) with an arduino uno r3.

I connected the collector to +5volts and the emitter to ditital pin 0.

Now, since there is no voltage applied to the gate and I haven't even connected the other side of the photocoupler (diode) with anything. Shouldn't it have an indication of LOW in the serial monitor? Instead it fluctuates between 0's and 1's.

I also gave it a try with the gate grounded, nothing...

I tried with a resistor to limit the current to the arduino, nothing...

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

By trying out the circuit of @Passerby the input pin was high. 
when i turned the gate High the pin went low. 
All is good so far.

what i want now is this depicted below.

[image]

when i replace the opto-isolator with a simple led (D1) it works. i tried it out.

The problem now is that the led in the opto-isolator is not bringing the gate high. why is this happening.

keep in mind that i only want to use this opto-isolator for this circuit.

and correction the capacitor is 150nF

Comment: You should have pinMode(0,INPUT_PULLUP) and not pinMode(0,INPUT) in your setup()

Comment: This is not a forum but a [Q&A site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour). Please don't change the question after it has been answered; if you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: You have not accounted for both AC cycles, and have probably killed your diodes or your optocoupler. Put another 1N4148 in parallel with the 2 you have, but reversed. And for God's sake reduce your capacitor to 1 uF or less.

Comment: since the vf of the photocoupler led is 1.4 v and 10mA. then R (instead of a capacitor) would be 22000 ohms. if you set R as the reactance Xc with frequency 50hz and solve for C = 145nF~150nF. it works for a normal LED why not for a photocouplers LED of same specs?

Answer (score 2):

Typical wiring for a on/off digital signal from an optocoupler is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv2FGx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Pull-up to VCC, most likely 5V for most Uno R3. The pull-up gives it a known state of HIGH when the optocoupler's LED isn't on. When the LED is on, the optocoupler's transistor turns on, pulling the collector towards ground, giving a LOW signal.

**Alternatively, wire the collector to the GPIO with the `pinMode(x,INPUT_PULLUP)` mode enable, using the internal ~47kΩ pull-up resistor. Essentially the same thing.**

This is a typical open-collector setup for digital logic.

**The Way you had it connected, with the emitter to the GPIO, is a emitter follower, and will show either 5V when the LED is ON or FLOATING when the LED is OFF**. A Floating input will not have a fixed state, and will float between states, like an antenna. Use the wiring above instead.

Comment: the two diodes in series are there to bring the forward to 1.4 volts. The circuit works with an led.